# OpenCV Chessboard Detection: Looking for Solutions to Identify and Extract Chessboard Squares

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, corner-detection

I am trying to write a program that could record chess moves played on a physical chessboard. The first step is to identify the chessboard and the individual squares. I have come up with a code that looks like it could work, but unfortunately, it's not functioning as expected. I have tried it on various chessboards with different viewing angles, but I still can't get it to work. After some research, I found that `cv2.findChessboardCorners` can be quite confusing. Can someone please help?

The following code is what I have tried. I expected it to find the chessboard, extract individual squares to temporary files, and print out the file names of the temporary files. However, I keep getting "Chessboard not found."

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tempfile

def extract_chessboard_squares(image_path, rows, columns):
    # Load the chessboard image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chessboard corners
    found, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (rows, columns), None)

    if found:
        # Refine the corner locations
        corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.1))

        # Create a 2D list to store file names of chessboard squares
        square_files = [[None] * columns for _ in range(rows)]

        # Iterate over each chessboard square
        for row in range(rows):
            for col in range(columns):
                # Calculate the square corners' coordinates
                pt1 = corners[row * columns + col]
                pt2 = corners[(row + 1) * columns + col]
                pt3 = corners[(row + 1) * columns + col + 1]
                pt4 = corners[row * columns + col + 1]

                # Create a mask for the current square
                mask = np.zeros_like(image)
                cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, np.int32([pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4]), (255, 255, 255))

                # Apply the mask to the original image
                masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)

                # Save the masked image to a temporary file
                _, temp_filename = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.jpg')
                cv2.imwrite(temp_filename, masked_image)

                # Store the temporary file name in the 2D list
                square_files[row][col] = temp_filename

        return square_files

    else:
        print("Chessboard not found.")
        return None

# Example usage:
image_path = 'path/to/chessboard_image.jpg'
rows = 8
columns = 8

result = extract_chessboard_squares(image_path, rows, columns)
if result:
    square_files = result
    # Use the square_files list as per your requirements
```

---

Make sure to replace `'path/to/chessboard_image.jpg'` with the actual path to your chessboard image file.

Comment: Can you try with row=column=7 ? These are the right values for a normal chessboard. These numbers are the number of INNER corners on each row and column, not the number of rows and columns.

Comment: occluded corners ruin the entire thing. robust detection and tracking isn't trivial.

Comment: @Lelouch how can i get the border of square that is not surrounded by inner corner(i.e. A and H file, 1 and 8 rank)

Comment: board-space translation. multiply onto homography from the left, assuming H transforms from image to board space

Answer (score 0):

following Lelouch suggestion this is what i came up with. note this solution is still not perfect as it ONLY extract the inner 6x6 squares that is surrounded by the 7x7 inner corners.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tempfile

def extract_chessboard_squares(image_path, rows, columns):
    inner_rows = rows - 1
    inner_columns = columns - 1
    # Load the chessboard image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chessboard inner corners
    found, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (inner_rows, inner_columns), None)

    if found:
        # Refine the corner locations
        corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.1))

        # Create a 2D list to store file names of chessboard squares
        square_files = [[None] * (columns-2) for _ in range(rows-2)]

        # Iterate over each chessboard square
        for row in range(rows-2):
            for col in range(columns-2):
                # Calculate the square corners' coordinates
                pt1 = corners[row * inner_columns + col]
                pt2 = corners[(row + 1) * inner_columns + col]
                pt3 = corners[(row + 1) * inner_columns + col + 1]
                pt4 = corners[row * inner_columns + col + 1]

                # Create a mask for the current square
                mask = np.zeros_like(image)
                cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, np.int32([pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4]), (255, 255, 255))

                # Apply the mask to the original image
                masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)

                # Save the masked image to a temporary file
                _, temp_filename = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.jpg')
                cv2.imwrite(temp_filename, masked_image)

                # Store the temporary file name in the 2D list
                square_files[row][col] = temp_filename

        return square_files

    else:
        print("Chessboard not found.")
        return None

# Example usage:
image_path = r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\chess_board.jpg'
rows = 8
columns = 8

result = extract_chessboard_squares(image_path, rows, columns)
```